# Asterisk - Record calls using MixMonitor for outbound calls

Tags: sip, voip, asterisk, telephony, asteriskami

I have a macro set up to record inbound calls on an extension:

```
[macro-DialStartMonitor]
; Calculate the time of the call from "epoch time", format it into yyyy-mm-dd and add the PhoneExt. at the end
exten => s,1,Set(MONITOR_FILENAME=${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},,%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)}-FROM-${CALLERID(num)}-TO-${ARG1})
        same => n,MixMonitor(${MONITOR_FILENAME}.wav,b)

exten => 1001,1,noop(Dialing ${PEX_ONE})
        same => n,Macro(DialStartMonitor,${PEX_ONE})
        same => n,Dial(SIP/${PEX_ONE},30,mTt)
        same => n,Playback(vm-nobodyavail)      ; Play "no one's available"
        same => n,Hangup()

exten => 1002,1,noop(Dialing ${PEX_TWO})
        same => n,Macro(DialStartMonitor,${PEX_TWO})
        same => n,Dial(SIP/${PEX_TWO},30,mTt)
        same => n,Playback(vm-nobodyavail)      ; Play "no one's available"
        same => n,Hangup()
```

Thus, when I make a call from **1002** to **1001**, the recording is saved to `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor` with a format like this example "*20140106-122313-FROM-1002-TO-PExten1001.wav*"

I need to record the outbound call that originated from 1002 as it's own separate file - that is, when a call is made from **1002** to **1001**, 2 recordings are made, one is an inbound recording for 1001(which is the code above) and one is an outbound recording for 1002(which is what this question is about).

Do I have to write a separate context for both the extensions? Or is there another method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do 2 monitor on SAME channel.

To do what you want you have 2 variants

1) Create script on hangup which will copy file(recommended way)

2) Dial via Local/soemexte@somecontext/n and create enother monitor inside somecontext.

Comment: Thank you, I chose the 1st method. I am now trying to write the script which will copy the file